# Application_ItemSend not firing on replies/forwarding

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm having a problem where my Outlook add-in works when composing a new email in a separate window. However, when you go to reply or forward it while on the main Window, my user prompt does not show up. It seems like at some point the code is not catching the event Outlook spits out.

If anyone has any thoughts, I'd really appreciate it!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using System.Windows.Forms;




namespace AutoMarkings
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
         private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Application.ItemSend += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend) 
        }

        void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
        {
            Outlook.Inspector inspector = Application.ActiveInspector();

            if (inspector != null)
            {
                object item = inspector.CurrentItem;

                        Outlook.MailItem mail = Item as Outlook.MailItem;
                        string PR_SECURITY_FLAGS = @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x6E010003";
                        int sec = mail.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_SECURITY_FLAGS);

                    if (item is Outlook.MailItem)
                    {
                        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("SAMPLE MESSAGE", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);

                        if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
                        {
                            Cancel = true;
                        }

                        else if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                        {
                            var recips = mail.Recipients;
                            bool external = false;

                            for (int i = recips.Count; i >= 1; i--)
                            {
                                Outlook.Recipient recip = (Outlook.Recipient)recips[i];
                                Outlook.PropertyAccessor pa = recip.PropertyAccessor;
                                const string PR_SMTP_ADDRESS =
                                            "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E";

                                string smtpAddress =
                                    pa.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS).ToString();


                                if (!smtpAddress.Contains("@COMPANYDOMAIN"))
                                {
                                    external = true;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                            if (sec > 31)
                            {
                                sec = sec % 32;
                            }


                            if (external == true)
                            {
                                if ((sec == 0) || (sec == 2))
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("This email is being sent to an external address. Please encrypt the message and send again.");
                                    Cancel = true;
                                }
                            }

                            if (Cancel == false && mail != null)
                            {
                                var attachments = mail.Attachments;
                                string addToBody = "SAMPLE BODY";
                                List<string> list = new List<string>();

                                if (!mail.HTMLBody.Contains(addToBody)) mail.HTMLBody = (addToBody + "<br/>" + "<br/>" + mail.HTMLBody);

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    
                
            }
        }

       
        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e) { }

        # region VSTO generated code /// <summary>

        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        # endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course - your code is checking if `Application.ActiveInspector != null`. There won't be an inspector if you are sending using an inline reply.

And you don't need an inspector - you only use it to retrieve `Inspector.CurrentItem` - there is really no need: the item being sent is passed as a parameter to your event jhandler.

Answer (score 0):

The item being sent  is passed as a parameter:

```
void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
     object item = Item;
     //  your code goes there
}
```

See [Application.ItemSend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.itemsend) for more information.

Note, you can use the [Explorer.ActiveInlineResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.explorer.activeinlineresponse) property which returns an item object representing the active inline response item in the explorer reading pane, but not in the `ItemSend` event. Here use the item passed as a parameter.